# Menu tabs that change color, but keep the code simple

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, menubar

I need a simple tabbed menu that changes the content of a div box. I want the code to be short (few lines of code).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what your want. Your description is confusing, the code isn't even close to working and nothing in your code has anything to do changing color.

Comment: Your right about the code not being close to working.  In any event, I changed the question to simplify and clarify my request. I thought the new question would be more concise and helpful to others in regard to why I chose the answer that I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ - much more simple to setup and it is much more solid than your current approach.

Comment: I like it.  It adds just a few lines of code to my script which is what I wanted. Thanks.